# can we map non-object propety to an object in Many-to-one relationship of hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a very specific scenario as follow.

```
public class Person
{
    Long id;
    Collection<PersonRelation> personRelationCollection = new LinkedHashSet<PersonRelation>();
/**
  has respective getter and setter
**/
}

public class PersonRelation
{
    Long id;
    Long parentPersonId;  // here I don't want parentPersonId of type Person
    Long childPersonId;   // here also I don't want childPersonId of type Person
    String relationType;
/**
  has respective getter setter
**/
}
```

In my mapping files I have following

```
<class name="Person" table="PERSON">
     <id name="id" column="IDENTIFIER">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set 
        name="personRelationCollection"
        table="PERSON_RELATION"
        cascade="all"
       >
       <key column="PARENT_PERSON_ID"/>
       <one-to-many class="PersonRelation"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

and

```
<class name="PersonRelation" table="PERSON_RELATION">
    <id name="id" column="IDENTIFIER">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

   <!-- following many-to-one mapping doesn't work-->
   <!-- I need help here to satisfy my requirement -->
    <many-to-one 
          name="parentPersonId" 
          column="PARENT_PERSON_ID"
          class="Person"
          not-null="true"/>   
    <Property name="childPersonId" column="CHILD_PERSON_ID"/>
    <property name="relationType" column="RELATION_TYPE"/>    
</class>
```

In this example, as in PersonRelation class, attribute parentPersonId is Long and not type of Person, I'm getting 
**org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class PersonRelation**
$
Please help.

Comment: does your person class compile? You don't have a name of the collection variable, or is this just a typo in the question?

Comment: sorry, it was typo. I set collection name. There is no compilation error.

Comment: Why dont you map to type Person and load lazy? Can you explain the reason for trying to map to long? In the db the mapping will be to the long id either way.

Comment: Yes, I can map to type Person and load lazy, but it is a extra load to populate Person object lazy. And will become bidirectional accessibility which I don't want. Anyways, thanks for reply, I found answer. Posting below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found answer my own. Very small thing we have to do as follow.

```
<class name="PersonRelation" table="PERSON_RELATION">
    <id name="id" column="IDENTIFIER">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

   <!-- here remove many-to-one mapping ---- it's not needed-->
   <!-- treet participantPersonId as a simple property and everything will work --> 
    <Property name="parentPersonId" column="PARENT_PERSON_ID" type="Long"/>

    <Property name="childPersonId" column="CHILD_PERSON_ID"/>
    <property name="relationType" column="RELATION_TYPE"/>    
</class>
```

This works perfectly fine. :)

Here, when you insert Person object, then it will not inset PersonRelation object too. You have to explicitly insert PersonRelation object. Perhaps, when we retrieve Person object, then it will gives you collection of PersonRelation. Here no need to retrieve PersonRelation collection explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about references by id. In Hibernate you work with objects, not tables.
I guess your code could be written like this:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="your_table")  
public class Item{  

   private Long id;  
   private Item parentItem;  
   private List<Item> children;  

   @Id  
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)  
   public Long getId(){  
   }  

   @ManyToOne()//Your options  
   public Item getParentItem(){  
   }  

   @OneToMane(mappedBy="parentItem")  
   public List<Item> getChildren(){  
   }  

   //Setters omitted  
}
```